# position: fixed prevents elements to be centered properly

Tags: html, css

I want to center `.donut-graphs` inside `.dashboard` horizontally, so the space between the right edge of the sidebar and the left edge of `.donut-graphs` is the same as the space from the right edge of `.donut-graphs` and the right edge of the screen. I have managed to do so, but I had to remove `position: fixed` from `.navbar`. The problem is, I can't do that because my sidebar has to stay on top of the screen when you scroll up/down, and with `position: fixed` on `.navbar`, the graphs aren't centered properly.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="dashboard">
      <div class="donut-graphs">
        <div class="dashboard-income">
          Div 1
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-overall">
          Div 2
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-spent">
          Div 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #ddd;
  flex: 0 0 230px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 230px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.donut-graphs {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.dashboard-income,
.dashboard-overall,
.dashboard-spent {
  height: 256px;
  width: 357px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dashboard-income {
  background-color: green;
}

.dashboard-overall {
  background-color: blue;
}

.dashboard-spent {
  background-color: red;
}
```

How can I overcome the issue?

[Demo](https://codepen.io/lbastos/pen/JjjmxBW)

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` puts element above everything. That element won't attach to any element in body because it is the way that works. It only becomes dependent of viewport

What you want to achive could be done with `position: absolute` but parent (whose child you want to center) has to be `position: relative` for this to work.

Read more about positioning elements in css [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

`.content { padding-left:230px; }`

Should do the trick.
Assigning your navbar a fixed position takes it out of the document flow, so when centering your donut graphs the browser doesn't take the navbar into account.

Giving the `.content` element a padding equivalent to the width of the navbar makes up for this.

The only problem with this approach is that if `.navbar` changes dimensions, you'll need to change the padding on `.content` to match.